# What is the difference of `induction n, m` and `induction n; induction m` in Coq?

Tags: coq

I tough that `induction n, m` would create induction hypothesis for `n` and `m` but after some tries this seems not be the case. BTW I'm assuming `forall (n m : nat)`.

So what is the difference of `induction n, m` `induction n. induction m` and `induction n; induction m`?

Here is my currently understanding:

I know that `;` is a combinator so that `a; b` replays `b` on every subgoal generated by `a`, so `induction n; induction m` will generate an induction hypotesis for m for each subgoal of `induction n` is this right?

And in the same sense `induction n. induction m` would generate induction hypotesis only for the current goal so that this seems not particularly useful

I expected `induction n, m` to be like *induct on this two variables* this generate four goals for natural numbers as I expected, but I expected `IHm` to be on context on the 4th goal but it isn't! What I'm missing?

--

Still researching on this, it seems that the IHm is merged in IHn at the 4th goal, is this correct?

-- edit 2

Here is some example based on addition commutativity

So first the `induction n, m` version:

```
Example add_comm' : forall (n m : nat), n + m = m + n.
  intros. induction n, m; try auto using plus_n_O.
```

This solves the trivial 3 first goals and leave me with the 4th goal with

```
n, m : nat
IHn : n + S m = S m + n

========================= (1 / 1)

S n + S m = S m + S n
```

Now the `induction n; induction m` version:

```
n, m : nat
IHn : n + S m = S m + n
IHm : n + m = m + n -> S n + m = m + S n

========================= (1 / 1)

S (n + S m) = S (m + S n)
```

So for this particular case `induction n, m` is better but I can't explain (and understand) what it is doing.

In the manual the only case for `,` in induction is

> Variant `induction term+, using qualid`
>
> This syntax is used for the case qualid denotes an induction principle with complex predicates as the induction principles
> generated by Function or Functional Scheme may be.

But I'm not using `using qualid` so I'm not sure if this is the case

-- edit 3 --

As Andrey said in its comment, the `using qualid` variant is the one being triggered but I have no idea what is the explanation for what it does.

Comment: Can you include a small example?

Comment: Well, as far as I know you are absolutely right about `induction n; induction m.` and `induction n. induction m.` I would only say that `And in the same sense induction n. induction m would generate induction hypotesis only for the current goal so that this seems not particularly useful` is a bit not accurate since sometimes you need the 2nd induction only in one of the branches...

As for `induction n, m`, according to the documentation it should be used together with some kind of complicated predicate. I think that is why behaviour is not like you expected. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: So, I think if you provide a predicate `P` depending from two variables to `induction n, m using P`, it will work correctly. See documentation here https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.induction , search for  "Variant induction term" and "using qualid"  in one sentense somewhere on the page.

Comment: Hmmm so is that `using qualid` variant that is being triggered, thank you I will look at it, thank you Andrey!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`induction n, m` is the same as `induction n; destruct m`.  The reason for this is that it's quite rare that you actually want two induction hypotheses, and in cases where you do, you probably don't want `induction n; induction m` because the induction hypothesis for `m` will not be appropriately general over `n`.

The reference manual for 8.15 will be much more complete than the reference manual for 8.14, and you can find this documented in [the current documentation for the master branch](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html?highlight=induction#coq:tacn.induction):

> If no induction_principle clause is provided, this is equivalent to doing induction on the first induction_clause followed by destruct on any subsequent clauses.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the current manual documentation link, I usually type (coq index) in google and hit the first link.

Comment: @geckos There is a drop-down menu in the bottom left corner of the reference manual where you can pick the version. (But I usually don't check the master version of the refman either.)